# Get all records

Tags: php, odoo

I have the following code in php to connect through XML-RPC :

```
$key = array(new xmlrpcval('id','integer'), new xmlrpcval('name', 'string'), new xmlrpcval('requirements','string'),new xmlrpcval('description','string'));

$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->db, "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(1, "int"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("hr.job","string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("read", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($ids, "array"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($key, "array"));

$resp    = $client->send($msg);
$val     = $resp->value();
$scalval = $val->scalarval();
```

everything is working alright but I would like to read all the records in `hr_job` without providing ids , something like `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: Help get the OpenERP StackExchange site going: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43481/openerp?referrer=CbZ7bL3fh2QdmpKS2kqovw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way OpenERP works requires you to get the list of ids first, then use those ids to get any further results.

Fortunately, you can use `(1,'=',1)` to get all ids.

I don't use PHP, but hopefully this is still helpful.

Comment: it's looks like Sql injection lol,Excellent it's works perfectly !! (y) you saved my life